# cannot collapse toolbar from tab content

Tags: java, android

I am starting with android development and I am trying to implement scroll in my application based on co-ordinator layout.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">




    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/days_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

This is one of my tab content

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/one"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am able to scroll and collapse when recycler view is filled with some data.However when I remove recycler view I am not able to collapse the toolbar based on my tab content.How can i collapse the toolbar based on my tab content.?